# changing the checked property of checkbox in angular2

Tags: angular

I have a list displaying all the columns in the grid in the following template manner

```
<ul id="gridColumnList" class="gridColumnList">
    <li *ngFor="let col of grid.colModel">
        <span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox col-visibility" **[checked]="!col.hidden"** /></span>
        <span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox col-freeze" [checked]="col.locked" **[disabled]="col.hidden"** /></span>
        <span class="col-title">{{col.label}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to change the state of the checkbox input based on the `col.hidden` value which is a boolean type but the property binding does not work instead if interpolation is used like `checkbox = {{col.hidden}}` it works. what is wrong with the property binding?

Answer (score 1):

remove all "**"

```
<span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox col-visibility" [checked]="!col.hidden"/></span>
```

add a [testing plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/c88cpa9rSdeVyLjkgLrL/)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: ** is not there. its written in the same manner as you wrote. ** was to distinguish as bold